# 2008 Chevrolet Impala. Clicking noise behind the glove box - I believe it has something to do with a diverter valve in heating and cooling system?

Tags: troubleshooting, chevrolet, hvac

There is a clicking noise behind the glove box. I believe there should be a sensor or something to stop the motor for the divertor valve. It trys to keep shifting the valve and it clicks when it reaches the bottom but doesn't stop. Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a blend/vent door actuator motor.

I've had two go bad my self and they make a really bad noise when they go bad. I imagine if the potentiometer goes bad in them they could continually actuate without getting a signal to stop.